# Inline Assembly Code Does Not Compile in Visual C++ 2010 Express

Tags: c++, visual-c++, assembly, inline-assembly

I have some assembly merge sort code that I obtained from Github and I am trying to embed it into Inline Assembly in C++, but it won't compile and keeps returning these errors:

> 1>c:\users\mayank\desktop\assembly\assembly\main.cpp(147): error
>   C2415: improper operand type

The code that I am attempting to run is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
const int ARRAYSIZE = 30;

int main()
{
    int arr[ARRAYSIZE];
    int temp_arr[ARRAYSIZE];
    int number;

    for(int x = 0; x < ARRAYSIZE; x++)
    {
        number = (rand() % 99) + 1;
        arr[x] = number;
    }
/*  
READ_ARR_LEN:
    __asm
    {
        // Read the length of the array
        //GetLInt [30]      // Size of input array
        //PutLInt [30]
    }

GET_ARRAY:
    __asm
    {
         //intel_syntax
         // Get values in arr from the user
         mov   EAX, arr
         mov   ECX, ARR_LEN
         call  Read_Arr

         // Run Merge Sort on the array
         mov   EAX, arr
         mov   EBX, temp_arr
         mov   ECX, ARR_LEN
         call  Merge_Sort

        // EXIT
    };;
*/
Merge_Sort:
    __asm
    {
        // EAX - Array start
        // ECX - array length

        // Arrays of size 0 or 1 are already sorted
        cmp   ARRAYSIZE, 2
        jl    Trivial_Merge_Sort

        // Merge_Sort (first half)
        // Length of the first half
        // ECX /= 2
        push  ARRAYSIZE
        shr   ARRAYSIZE, 1
        call  Merge_Sort
        pop   ARRAYSIZE

        // Merge_Sort (second half)
        push  arr
        push  EBX
        push  ARRAYSIZE

        // Length of the second half
        // ECX = ECX - ECX/2
        mov   EDX, ARRAYSIZE
        shr   EDX, 1
        sub   ARRAYSIZE, EDX
        imul  EDX, 4
        // Start index of the second half
        // EAX = EAX + (ECX/2) * 4
        add   arr, EDX
        push  EDX
        call  Merge_Sort
        pop   EDX

        pop   ARRAYSIZE
        pop   EBX
        pop   arr

        pushad
        // Merge (first half, second half)
        // Length of first half = ECX/2
        // Length of second half = ECX - ECX/2
        mov   EDX, ECX
        shr   ECX, 1
        sub   EDX, ECX

        // Start of second half = EAX + (ECX/2) * 4
        mov   EBX, EAX
        mov   EDI, ECX
        imul  EDI, 4
        add   EBX, EDI
        // Index of temp array = 0
        sub   EDI, EDI
        call  Merge
        popad

        // Copy back the merged array from temp_arr to arr
        call  Merge_Copy_Back_Temp

        ret
    };

Trivial_Merge_Sort:
    __asm
    {
        // In case of arrays of length 0 or 1
        ret
    };
Merge:
    __asm
        {
        // Merge two arrays contents.
        // The final merged array will be in temp_arr
        // Merging is done recursively.

        // Arguments:
        // EAX - First array's start
        // EBX - Second array's start
        // ECX - Length of first array
        // EDX - Length of second array
        // EDI - Index in temp array
        pushad

        // Handle the cases where one array is empty
        cmp   ARRAYSIZE, 0
        jz    First_Array_Over
        cmp   EDX, 0
        jz    Second_Array_Over

        // Compare first elements of both the arrays
        push  ARRAYSIZE
        push  EDI
        mov   ARRAYSIZE, [arr]
        mov   EDI, [ARRAYSIZE]
        cmp   ARRAYSIZE, EDI
        pop   EDI
        pop   ARRAYSIZE

        // Pick which ever is the least and update that array
        jl    Update_First_Array
        jmp   Update_Second_Array
    };

Update_First_Array:
   __asm
   {
        // min_elem = min (first elements of first array and second array)
        // Put min_elem into the temp array
        push  dword ptr [EAX]
        pop   dword ptr [temp_arr + EDI * 4]
        add   EAX, 4
        dec   ECX
        inc   EDI

        // Recursively call Merge on the updated array and the
        // other array
        call  Merge
        popad
        ret
   };

Update_Second_Array:
   __asm
   {
       // min_elem = min (first elements of first array and second array)
        // Put min_elem into the temp array
        push  dword ptr [EBX]
        pop   dword ptr [temp_arr + EDI * 4]
        add   EBX, 4
        dec   EDX
        inc   EDI

        // Recursively call Merge on the updated array and the
        // other array
        call  Merge
        popad
        ret
   };

Merge_Copy_Back_Temp:
   __asm
   {
        // Copy back the temp array into original array
        // Arguments:
        // EAX - original array address
        // ECX - original array length
        pushad

        // For copying back, the destination array is EAX
        mov   EBX, EAX
        // Now, the source array is temp_arr
        mov   EAX, temp_arr
        call  Copy_Array
        popad
        ret
   };

Trivial_Merge:
   __asm
   {
        // Note: One array is empty means no need to merge.
        popad
        ret
   };

First_Array_Over:
   __asm
   {
        // Copy the rest of the second array to the temp arr
        // because the first array is empty
        pushad
        mov   EAX, EBX
        mov   ECX, EDX
        mov   EBX, temp_arr
        imul  EDI, 4
        add   EBX, EDI
        call  Copy_Array
        popad
        popad
        ret
   };

Second_Array_Over:
   __asm
   {
    // Copy the rest of the first array to the temp arr
    // because the second array is empty
    pushad
    mov   EBX, temp_arr
    imul  EDI, 4
    add   EBX, EDI
    call  Copy_Array
    popad
    popad
    ret
   }; 
Copy_Array:
   __asm
   {
    // Copy array to destination array
    // EAX - Array start
    // EBX - Destination array
    // ECX - Array length

    // Trivial case
    cmp   ECX, 0
    jz    Copy_Empty_Array

    push  ECX
    sub   EDI, EDI
   };
copy_loop:
   __asm
   {
    // Copy each element
    push  dword ptr [EAX + EDI * 4]
    pop   dword ptr [EBX + EDI * 4]
    inc   EDI
    loop  copy_loop

    pop   ECX
    ret
   };

Copy_Empty_Array:
   __asm
   {
    ret
   };

Read_Arr:
   __asm
   {
        // EAX - array start
        // ECX - array length
        mov   ESI, EAX
        sub   EDI, EDI
   };
loop1:
   __asm
   {
        // Read each element
        lea eax,[esi+edx*4]
        inc   EDI
        loop  loop1
        ret
   };

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you needing so much inline assembly? Don't you trust the compiler to optimize the code properly? Do you have a fetish for unmaintainable code?

Comment: Note that I've made two edits: 1) We don't care to see the same error repeated N times. 2) The title: the problem is not that your code does not **run**, it is that it does not **compile**. There is a *huge* difference, and it is imperative that you understand the difference.

Comment: Are you using a 64-bit compiler? If so, the you'll have to find a different way to solve this problem. Are you sure that it's meaningful to do a hand-assembled merge-sort, vs. what the compiler produces? And if so, I guess you would get a bit more performance if you stopped using pushad/popad.

Comment: I'm using inline just for testing and experimenting. This is not going to be an actual program I use. It is just for personal learning. I also understand the difference. I didn't realize I said run. Also, what should I use instead of pushad/popad?

Comment: @Mayankmmmx - We have seen this before and it is not very good assembly code. You would be much better of using `std::stable_sort` from the C++ library. It is *very* likely to use a merge sort. And actually work.

Comment: @BoPersson I know that it isn't the best way to approach sorting. The reason i am using this is to learn how to embed assembly so I want this code to work so I can know why it works.

Answer (score 3):

(**Update:** In the original code posted in the question there were attempts to address memory as `DWORD [address]`, which is incompatible with the syntax used by Visual C++'s inline assembler as I point out in my answer below.)

Visual C++ uses MASM syntax for its inline assembly, so you need to use `DWORD PTR` instead of just `DWORD`. That's what's causing these compilation errors.

See e.g. [this table](http://cs.smith.edu/~thiebaut/ArtOfAssembly/CH08/CH08-5.html) from The Art of Assembly.

Comment: I really appreciate you're help! I compiled the code again and only got one error! The error was: 1>c:\users\mayank\desktop\assembly\assembly\main.cpp(289): error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'opcode'; found '['

Comment: Probably the `GetLInt [ESI + EDI * 4]` line. I'm not sure what `GetLInt` is supposed to be (a function that you've declared and defined elsewhere?). In that case, that's not how you do a function call in x86 assembly. You'd have to do something like `lea eax,[esi+edx*4] / push eax / call GetLInt`, and after that the return value should be in `eax` if the function follows standard calling conventions.

Comment: It turns out that I forgot this code:
READ_ARR_LEN:
 __asm
 {
  // Read the length of the array
  GetLInt [30]     // Size of input array
  PutLInt [30]
 }

But, now when I run the code, I get these errors:
1>c:\users\mayank\desktop\assembly\assembly\main.cpp(31): error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'opcode'; found '['

(Repeated on line 32)

Since I added more code, the line 31 and 32 are:
 GetLInt [30]     //Size of input array
 PutLInt [30]

And since I made the above edit, line 297 is:
lea eax,[esi+edx*4] call GetLInt

Comment: I suggested `call` because I thought `GetLInt` was a function that you were trying to call. Since you say now that's an array (of `int` or `long`?) you shouldn't be calling it. And `GetLInt[30]` is not a valid x86 assembly instruction. You should probably update your original post with your complete current code, point out at which lines you're getting compilation errors, and what your intention was with those failing lines of code (i.e. what were you trying to do?).

Comment: I updated the code above as well as the errors I am getting. Basically, the purpose of the functions is to call the array and then read each element.

Comment: To the downvoter: care to explain why you downvote an answer where I point out an actual syntactic error in the OP's code as he originally presented it? The fact that the OP has since modified his question to include my suggested change does not merit a downvote, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the code is from [this github repository](https://github.com/pradeep90/CSD-Lab/tree/master/Merge-Sort).

In that code, `GetLInt` is actually a NASM macro which is included in an external macro definition file and calls a function `proc_GetLInt`, which in turn is provided in an object file `io.o`, the source code is not there. The problem is therefore simply that

- you didn't realize that `GetLint` is external code that you're missing
- even if you took all files from that repository, it would work because NASM macros don't work directly in VC++ inline assembly
- even if you fixed the macro problem, you still don't have the `GetLInt` function because it is provided as a linux object file only, you'd have to write it yourself

---

How do you fix this?

That code was meant to provide a self-contained assembler program that handles all input/output on its own. Since you're inlining it in VC++, you have much more powerful I/O handling at your hands already. Use those instead, i.e. make sure that the values you want to sort are already in `arr` before the inline assembly starts.

Then, looking at the code: `Merge_Sort` expects the start of your array in `EAX`, and its length in `ECX`. You can get both from your C++ code. When you do that, you no longer need the `READ_ARR_LEN` and `GET_ARRAY` blocks from the assembler code.

I am rather reluctant to reproduce parts of the code with modifications as I cannot find a licence file on github that would say I may do so. Let me try to describe: You need to manually move the pointer to `arr` into `EAX` and the content of `ARRAYSIZE` into `EBX` at the very start of the assembler routine. (*) As I can see, you have already taken care of filling the array with numbers, so there's nothing you need to do there.

Then you need to remove all unnecessary assembler functions and calls to them. You also should either condense all your separate `__asm` blocks into one or use external variables to conserve and restore registers between blocks ([or read the tutorial here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1a8ss06.aspx), but just using one block works and is less hassle).

Finally, you have to be careful with the stack frames: every `call` has to have a matching `ret`. This is easy to stumble over as the merge sort procedure is recursive.

(*) Careful with VC++'s way of treating variables in inside asm blocks, be sure to actually use pointers when you need them.

So all in all, porting this to VC++ is not a trivial task.

Comment: Yes I did take the code from the Github repository as a source to test inline assembly with. And that makes much more sense of why it doesn't work. I don't fully understand what you mean by what I should replace the GetLInt function with.

Comment: @mayankmmmx: Wow, just wow. In your question, you're claiming: `... that I wrote in Inline Assembly in C++ ...` . I must say I'm a little annoyed at that. You clearly *did not* write it.

Comment: I didn't realize I said that. What I was trying to say was that I translated it into inline assembly. I apologize for this and edited that statement. Can you please help me resolve my issue?

Comment: @Mayankmmmx: Okay, good thing you edited your question :) . I have provided some additional info in my answer that may help you fix your problem. Let me know if that's enough.

Comment: It was definitely my mistake and I should have not said that :). Now to my question, How would I add the start of the array and array length to the Merge_Sort if I take out READ_ARR_LEN and GET_ARR?

Comment: @Mayankmmmx With the steps I have described above, you should be able to reconstruct this into a working C++ program. As I said, I don't want to post code, as there is no license attached to the github repository that says I'm allowed to. If you're having trouble with the basics (like getting the array length into ECX), there are some good tutorials on Microsoft's pages on inline assembler. But honestly, if you struggle with that, try some easier inline assembler things first!

Comment: I appreciate your help in this and would like your input on one last thing. I have made the changes you mention above, but am still getting an error. I have updated the code in my initial question as well as the error i am getting.

Comment: There is no `mov %m32, %m32` in x86 assembly, so `mov ARRAYSIZE, [arr]` can't work without an intermediate step. Besides, even if it would work, it doesn't really make sense?

Comment: Also, I see you have replaced all occurences of `ECX` by `ARRAYSIZE`. That is not correct! `ECX` is reused for other purposes, and the array size is different for the recursively handled parts!

Comment: SO which ECX should I be replacing?

Comment: I'm sorry, but you should learn assembly first. I can't provide full working code to you because of the license reasons, and I can't explain it to you if you don't have a basic understanding of how assembler works.

Comment: Could you try explaining what I should do? I will attempt to decode your words. Please.